# REPLACE not removing the correct characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the query : `SELECT ','+ REPLACE(wo_note, '  ', '')`, basically I want to remove the characters 'amp;' but it does remove it when I am entering it, `SELECT ','+ REPLACE(wo_note, 'amp;  ', '')`

I want to change this `'R&amp;R # 10 tire'` to this `'R&R # 10 tire'`.

Comment: Please pay attention to the preview/posted question to realise that your edits back are making your question *less* readable by giving `&amp;` and `&` exactly the same appearance.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you type `SELECT ',' + REPLACE(wo_note, 'amp;', ''),` in your tool, but in the moment you type it, it gets converted to `SELECT ',' + REPLACE(wo_note, '', ''),`? What tool is that?

Comment: SELECT ',' + REPLACE (wo_note, 'amp;', '') ......When I use this the result should be "R&R # 10 tire" but instead it doesn't remove any characters and gives me "R&amp;R # 10 tire"

Comment: select replace ('R&amp;R # 10 tire','amp;','') gives R&R # 10 tire. What do you get?

Comment: That gives me the required result "R&R # 10 tire"

Comment: @Danish Shoaib - Great, Could you mark and votethe answers please? This will help visitors of Stack overflow community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below,

```
select replace ('R&amp;R # 10 tire','amp;','')

R&R # 10 tire
```

Check the dbfiddle link for the solution https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c78ae4653b7278bdda877c520c3742a

Answer (score 0):

SELECT REPLACE('R&R # 10 tire', '&', '')
Gets you - RR # 10 tire

SELECT REPLACE('R&R # 10 tire', '&', '')
Gets you - RR # 10 tire

You need to select the field in sql and post exactly what is contained in that field for better help.  Also, your desired result is the same as that you are starting with, which I think is just a mistake.

i.e.  "I want to change this 'R&R # 10 tire' to this 'R&R # 10 tire'"   The values are the exact same.  Please clarify the question.

[image]

Comment: I typed & amp ; here without spaces, but it changed it to an ampersand.  Thats probably what happened to you.  In any case, you have the replace syntax correct, it should find it.   It works fine for me in SQL using both  "&"  and   "& amp ;"  (without  the spaces)

Comment: Use backticks to surround small code blocks and the SO editor won't assume you're giving it HTML - in which `&amp;` is a named entity.

Comment: It was meant to change from "R&amp;R # 10 tire" to "R&R # 10 tire"